# Monitoring Port Requests for Command

Tags: linux, port, ps

I have a command which I am running that starts a process listening on a port. I am currently getting the following error.

```
socket exception: Address already in use
```

The problem is, I don't know what port the process is trying to listen on. Is there a way for me to monitor what port the process is trying to access?

I would post the code, but it is unfortunately not possible. I am running Redhat.

Comment: I believe `strace` will show what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strace` will show you system calls, including what ports a given process tries to use.